# Red (!) Exclamation after extending ubuntu partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I had a dual boot win 10 and ubuntu 20.04. I needed more space, so I deleted win 10 partition and extended ubuntu using live disc. It seems it didn't go right. I appreciate any help with fixing this issue. I am still able to boot into ubuntu fortunately.

[image: Image Here]

Comment: --------------- First, do not attempt any partition operations without solid backups. You have been warned! ------------
You cannot resize a mounted partition. The key icon tells you that the partition is mounted. I have not seen the exclamation mark icon, but I am guessing that you tried to perform an operation on a mounted partition. Unmount the partition and try again.

Comment: okay, will try that after a back up. I did use live cd while attempting that. If you check the screenshot, I can't actually resize it anymore. It shows a 120gb, but actually it just shows the prev size. I guess gray area refers to that too.

Comment: I don't have option to re-do partition sizing. Here's the screenshot. https://i.imgur.com/ZZitrn4.png

Comment: You will probably have to enlarge the extended partition sda3 first and after that the sda5 inside it. But I am not sure about this, I avoid using extended partitions so I don't have much experience with them.

Comment: okay, np! I can't extend any partition anymore.

Comment: Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Ideally you should create an image of your disk on an external drive first. This would give you a chance of data recovery if it all goes wrong. The red ! Means there is a file system issue of some sort with that partition. You should attempt a fix by running a live environment. Ask other questions if you don’t know how to do this.

Comment: Fortunately, I was able to fix it. I first shrunk the space, and then expanded again (ext4) and it worked.